# Pass value from PHP page

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to pass value from Login.php page to Dashboard.php. However,it is not displaying any output.

Login.php

```
//there are no spaces before this
  <?php 
    session_start();
$username= $_POST["txtUsername"]; //it does contain a value

if (empty($_POST["txtUsername"])) {
    echo "<script> alert('Please enter username.')</script>";
               $url = 'Homepage.php';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 

}
else
{


$query= "Select User_ID, U_Username, U_Password from users where U_Username='$username' and U_Password='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($count==1) //and count is 1
    {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['U_Username'];       
        $url = 'Dashboard.php';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 
    }

}
    else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Invalid Username or Password.')</script>";
               $url = 'Homepage.html';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 

    }

}   
}
   ?>
```

Dashboard.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['login_user'];

    ?>
    //html code after this
```

When Dashboard.php is displayed it shows the result of the html code only and does not echo the session variable.

Kindly advise..

Comment: Not at home at the moment, so I can't test your code...but have tried viewing the sourecode of your page after dashboard is loaded? In dependency of your template (html code) the echo of *login_user* may just be not visible (but present in code)?

Comment: can you please tell from where you get `$row['U_Username']` and it have a value or not, please check.

Comment: Also, was the `session_start()` successful in both scripts? You can check its return value. Note that if you have output before that, like the spaces in your first script, it will fail. But that could be a copy-paste error just here of course.

Comment: Pbm is on your variables  $count / or $row['U_Username']. I replaced $count by 1 and $row by "bablablal" it displayed me "blalblalbla"

Comment: @anantkumarsingh U_Username is getting value from database. I have tried echoing and it contains a value.

Comment: I am saying that how it's come on that page where you get that variable? where is that variable code? i didn't see any where?

Comment: @jeron Yes, session_start() is successful in both the scripts. $_Session['login_user'] is displaying the correct value in login.php page. However, when it is echoed in Dashboard.php it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Can you show your full code of login page, that is how's `$count` and  `$row['U_Username']` is coming on that page. after seeing full code we will able to say what problem is their?

Comment: `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;` try that

Comment: @anantkumarsingh tried, didn't give any value. i have provided the full code now. Could you please review and advise..

Answer (score 0):

kindly check your if condition and the value of "$row['U_Username']". i put the value of $count & $row['U_Username'] hard coded and it show the output.

Comment: Tried hardcoding the values, as mentioned by @anantkumarsingh, still didn't display any output :S